# Griview row command event not firing with jquery mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

Hi i am working with jquery mobile application and facing a problem with Gridview rowcommand event firing.

Here is my code in aspx page

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grd_List" Width="100%" GridLines="none" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Style="margin-top: 0px;" OnRowCommand="Grd_List_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table data-role="table" id="table1" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive table1" data-column-btn-theme="c" data-column-popup-theme="c">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="thead">
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>PC</th>
                        <th>QC</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading"><strong>Part #</strong></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("pn-pc") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("pn-qc") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading"><strong>Closure Size</strong></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("xmlfile-pc") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("xmlfile-qc") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading"><strong>Quantity per Case</strong></td>
                    <td>72</td>
                    <td>72</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading"><strong>Price</strong></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Price-pc", "{0:C}") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Price-qc", "{0:C}") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Add to Cart</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="xmlfile_PC" Value='<%# Eval("xmlfile-pc") %>' />
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="qty_pc" name="text-basic" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_pc" CssClass="add-cart" CommandName="pc" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id-pc") %>'><i class="add-to-cart-icon"></i>Add to Cart</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="xmlfile_QC" Value='<%# Eval("xmlfile-qc") %>' />
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="qty_qc" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_qc" CssClass="add-cart" CommandName="qc" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id-qc") %>'><i class="add-to-cart-icon"></i>Add to Cart</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Here is code behind RowCommand event code:

```
protected void Grd_List_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "pc")
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;

        int CatID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        TextBox txtqtyPC = Grd_List.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("qty_pc") as TextBox;
        HiddenField xmlfile = Grd_List.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("xmlfile_PC") as HiddenField;
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtqtyPC.Text);


        Response.Redirect("view-cart.aspx?qty=" + qty + "&prinfo=" + CatID + "^" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "^" + xmlfile.Value);
    }
}
```

When i Browse through my application, this event is not firing..
any help?
Thanks

Comment: if am not wrong you need to make ItemTemplate for each column, not to put whole table in one itemTemplate

Comment: nope using multiple item templates not working aswell

Comment: you are trying to get command name as `pc` in code, well its missing in your markup instead of `pc' you have written `qc`

Comment: Please review my code carefully i have it there..

Comment: You need to work on your Gridview markup, puting whole table inside itemtemplate is really not a good idea, and it seperate and see still you facing same problem, **OR** use Repeater control

Comment: u still hvn't understood the problem.. button works without jquery mobile.. with jquery mobile it does not work.. simple

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register you even sample code also check properties `onrowdatabound="gv_RowDataBound"`

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Show Message
    LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnShowDetails") as LinkButton;
    if (lb != null)
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
}
```

Comment: Their is nothing wrong in using `Gridview1_RowCommand`.   `gv_RowDataBound` will bound on every row binding.